# Creating dinamicaly Markers and accessing by variables for Google Maps Api on Kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, marker

Im making a project where i need to add and remove some markers created dynamically. i'm creating my markes this way:

```
 private fun AddMarkerFromArray(name:String, adrs:String,cod:String,imgSrc:String){

    val info = MarkerDataNormal(name, adrs,
        cod )
    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
    markerOptions.position(LatLng(0.0,0.0))
        .title("Location Details")
        .snippet("I am custom Location Marker.")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)
            )
    val customInfoWindow = CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(this)
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow)
    val spot: Marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
    spot.tag = info
   // spot.showInfoWindow()
}
```

And this is the rest of code:

```
   data class MarkerDataNormal(val mLocatioName: String,
                        val mLocationAddres: String,
                        val mLocationCood: String)

   class CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap(val context: Context) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

   override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker?): View {

    var mInfoView = (context as Activity).layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.markernormal, null)
    var mInfoWindow: MarkerDataNormal? = p0?.tag as MarkerDataNormal?
    mInfoView.txtNombre.text = mInfoWindow?.mLocatioName
    mInfoView.txtDireccion.text = mInfoWindow?.mLocationAddres
    mInfoView.txtCoordenadas.text = mInfoWindow?.mLocationCood
    return mInfoView
}

override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker): View? {
    return null
   }
}
```

so i'm using the function to make apear all the Markers i need, they are displayed correctly, but i can't `clear()` only one cause every one of them are "spot"

how can i change the name of the variable or assign an id to each one for later access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store the references to the marker objects in a `List<Marker>`. This way you will have access to these references later.

Comment: 'im a bit confused by this, `List` works like array? if so.. can i assign a Key for each one? then `someKeyOfLlist.clear()` and that marker it's gone right?

Comment: You cannot use keys with `List`. To remove the markers from the map you can iterate over the list like this: `markerList.forEach { marker -> marker.remove() }`

Comment: I think this is the better answer seeing how you are using the tag. You could always use a different container for your data that could have a key assigned though.